# Words in sqlite showing up differently in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a SQL Server database that has a table which contains some Spanish words. I exported the table to a csv file so I could upload it into a sqlite table.

However letters with accents (like the two below) appear in my sqlite database like this, `Ense�ar`. How do I stop this?

Also some words which have no extra spacing have some of the weird question marks at the end like this word `abrazado��`, why is this?

```
 Enseñar
 sonreír
```

Answer (score 1):

1. When exporting your SQL data, use an unicode encoding (like utf8_general_ci). This will correct the error with non ASCII symbols.
2. The symbols at the end of words are likely "chariot return" symbols.
   Use the "trim" function to remove spaces before and after a string:
   https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php

Comment: Because a question is about Sql Server I think this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) is better

Comment: Close but no cigar, the `TRIM()` is only for SQL Server 2017 that was released this week, so I don't think he is using it, in other versions you should use `RTRIM(LTRIM())`. Anyway, in SQL Server the trim functions only remove spaces, if you need to remove return characters you can use `replace(replace(column,char(13),''),char(10),'')`

Comment: sorry how do you use a unicode encoder when exporting data in SQL?

Comment: @mHelpMe I never used SQL Server, but "file encoding type" should be in the options of the output file when exporting the data.